# OutOfMemoryError vs NegativeArraySizeException

Tags: java, stringbuffer

When i initialize the StringBuffer constructor with  **Integer.MAX_VALUE**            it throws `OutOfMemoryError` and when i add 16 to it it throws `NegativeArraySizeException`

```
  public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] arg) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 16);
            sb.append("A");
        }
    }
```

Can some one help me understand this behavior?

Comment: Int overflow...

Comment: Read up about integer overflow

Comment: 1st: ***Integer.MAX_VALUE + 16*** is an overflow that produce a negative number  → invalid argument

Comment: An `int` plus an `int` is always an `int`, even if the addition overflows the limits of an `int`.

Comment: I reopened this question because integer overflow may not be the only thing happening here.

Comment: 2nd: the outOfMemory is caused for the same reason as this: ***char[] x = new char[Integer.MAX_VALUE];***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have actually asked two entirely different questions here, so they must be addressed separately.

**1. Why does `new StringBuffer(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` throw an `OutOfMemoryError`?**

The `StringBuffer` constructor tries to instantiate an array of `char`, whose size is the value that you pass.  So you're implicitly trying to instantiate an array of size `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  There are two reasons why you might get an `OutOfMemoryError` from instantiating an array.

The first reason is that you genuinely don't have enough heap space.  Without knowing what else is going on in your program, or what your heap settings are, it's impossible for me to tell whether that might be happening for you.  But you can choose the maximum heap size for your JVM when you start it up,  with the `-Xmx` option.  Obviously, you'd need to set it to several gigabytes to get this to work (for example `-Xmx8g`), assuming your computer has enough RAM.

The second reason for an `OutOfMemoryError` when instantiating an array is that you've exceeded the maximum array size.  That's definitely happening here.  The maximum array size is not defined by the Java Language Specification, and it varies from JVM to JVM.  In most modern JVMs, the maximum array size is `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2`, but there are JVMs in which the maximum is  `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5` or `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8`.  In any case, `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is over the limit for sure.

**2. Why does `new StringBuffer(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 16)` throw a `NegativeArraySizeException`?**

This is to do with integer arithmetic in Java.  Any `int` value has to be between `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  Also, when you add two `int` values, the answer is guaranteed by the Java Language Specification to be an `int.  Therefore, when you evaluate`Integer.MAX_VALUE + 16`, you're not going to get the mathematically correct answer.  In fact, what Java does is to work mod 2<sup>32</sup>.  Another way of looking at it is that the JVM will add or subtract multiples of 2<sup>32</sup> to bring the answer within the correct range.

That means that the value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 16` will actually be numerically equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 16 -`2<sup>32</sup>, which is a large negative number.  As I mentioned earlier, the `StringBuffer` constructor tries to instantiate an array whose size is the value that you pass.  This attempt to instantiate an array of negative size gives you your `NegativeArraySizeException`.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `1` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` you will end up with `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. From here on you should know what happens when you add `16`:

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE + 16 == Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 + 15 == Integer.MIN_VALUE + 15
```

**Explanation**

Integers in *Java* are represented by 32-Bits while the most significant one (the left most bit) denotes the sign of the *Integer* (0 == positive, 1 == negative).

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is represented as: `01111111111111111111111111111111`. Adding `1` will flip all `1`s to `0`s and flip the left most `0` to `1` resulting in `10000000000000000000000000000000` which is a negative number, more specific `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

A `StringBuffer` uses a character array in its implementation to store a string.  Here is the constructor of its super class, `AbstractStringBuilder`, where the array actually gets allocated:

```
AbstractStringBuilder(int capacity) {
    value = new char[capacity];
}
```

As you can see, a new `char[]` array gets initialized with the capacity integer you passed in.  The max size for character arrays in Java is the *smaller* of the heap size or `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  If the following code threw an error, then my guess is that your heap ran out of memory:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

I would have expected this to work, assuming the heap had enough space.  But trying to allocate a `StringBuffer` of size `Integer.MAX_VALUE + 16` *can't* work, because it would exceed the max size of the underlying `char[]` array.

Comment: I maybe left out information about integer overflow, which also could be happening even before the array allocation takes place.  But this is one possible explanation for what is happening.

Comment: OOM  is justifiable but question here is Negative Integer exception ??